# Keys with generic type and default value

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma

I'm trying to set a default value `{ createdAt: 'asc' }` for a Generic Type, that will be used to create the keys inside `OrderByType`. I've already tried to use `Record` instead to create a new type, but the result was similar.

Here is my last try:

```js
type OrderByType<T> = {
  [key in keyof Partial<T>]: 'asc' | 'desc';
};

export class OrderByArgs<Entity extends { createdAt: Date }> {
  orderBy: OrderByType<Entity> = { createdAt: 'asc' };
}
```

Error:

`Type '{ createdAt: "asc"; }' is not assignable to type 'OrderByType<Entity>'.`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works, thank you. I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having with

```
type OrderByType<T> = { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: 'asc' | 'desc'; };
```

seems to be that it's too many nested layers of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for the compiler to "see" that `{ createdAt: 'asc' }` is assignable to `OrderByType<keyof Entity>` for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `Entity` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{ createdAt: Date }`.

This sort of issue was reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#27598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27598), although it was considered to be working as intended.  Generally speaking the compiler isn't great at knowing when some concrete type like `{createdAt: 'asc'}` is assignable to some generic type like `OrderByType<T>`, unless someone has explicitly written compiler code paths to handle it.

---

Luckily we can refactor your code for it to work:

[The `Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) just uses a [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to turn all the properties optional.  So your `OrderByType<T>` is essentially `{[K in keyof {[P in keyof T]?: T[P]}]: 'asc' | 'desc'}`, which puts an inner mapped type to add the optional modifier, and then an outer one to just keep these modifiers.

If you change it to the conceptually identical but simpler implementation

```
type OrderByType<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: 'asc' | 'desc' }
```

then things start working:

```
export class OrderByArgs<Entity extends { createdAt: Date }> {
  orderBy: OrderByType<Entity> = { createdAt: 'asc' }; // okay
```

Now it is obvious to the compiler that `OrderByType<T>` is definitely itself an all-optional type, and since `createdAt` is definitely a key of `Entity`, then `{createdAt: 'asc'}` is definitely assignable to `OrderByType<Entity>` no matter how many extra keys there are in `Entity`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgEwnAQiAKuCAedA+KAXigG8oBtABSgEsA7KAawhAHsAzKdAXQH4AuKAHIAhgGcAxkKgAfYUknSAvgCgVEAB5hWcYFAkAbcWNiJkaAIJwA5mOwBROsBqgom4BDoITZCXAgiHggWwIIAIoHQSgQkKlBQOkioIILwSWiYkA5OLiAExL7+kcGhwuJSUEoA3CqqKkA)